# HttpError 400 Precondition check failed during users().messages().list Gmail API call using service account

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I am using service account to list the message in my gmail box, however I am getting below error while calling this API `service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()`

```
    HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-da1dc3cccc81> in <module>
     27 
     28 apiservice = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=service_cred)
---> 29 response = apiservice.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129                     logger.warning(message)
--> 130             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    131         return positional_wrapper
    132 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    849       callback(resp)
    850     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 851       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    852     return self.postproc(resp, content)
    853 

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">
```

code:

```
scopes = [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
]

service_cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
                credentials, scopes=scopes)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=service_cred)
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran in to this as well when trying to list emails from my personal email. The Google dashboard set me up with service account credentials when enabling the Gmail API, so I assumed that was what I should use.

To make that 400 error go away, I had to add:

```
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('my-email@gmail.com')
```

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests.

However, I then got an error that my service account was unauthorized to make requests on behalf of my personal email.  And if you're not using G Suite, I don't think there's a way to use a service account on behalf of a user.

So the ultimate solution to my problem was to use the OAuth authentication like in the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time and replying. Yes, you are correct impersonate the user account using `with_subject` method solved the issue. I have found it on their documentation which is not so easy to find. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python

Comment: `And if you're not using G Suite, I don't think there's a way to use a service account on behalf of a user.`  I think I am learning this the hard way. Not sure why they do not mention that anywhere.

Comment: Reading here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2322 ... "The Gmail API isn't intended to be used with service accounts (other than domain-wide delegation use cases.) You need to be acting as a real user -- either using oauth credentials obtained with user consent, or in the case of a Gsuite domain, using a service account delegating/impersonating a real user."

Comment: I am using G Suite. Under the Domain-wide delegation, I've added the Service Account Client with the gmail.readonly scope. However, when I try your solution, I still get "Client is unauthorized...". Based on the comments above, it seems it should work since I have G-Suite. Am I missing something?